# SELECT top 3 customer with highest order count from Customer table and get sum of total for each customer from orders table

Tags: mysql, select

Customer table
[Customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5hNz.jpg)

Orders Table
[Orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IalcS.jpg)

I want to select top 3 customers with highest order count and the SUM of total from Orders for each customer id (custid)

I tried this

```
SELECT c.custid, c.name, c.order_count, SUM( o.total ) AS Totalspent 
FROM customer c INNER JOIN orders o ON c.custid = o.custid GROUP BY c.order_count DESC LIMIT 3
```

it fetches the data and groups by the order_count but the total is wrong. How do I get the correct total from orders for each customer (custid) while selecting the top 3 customers based on order count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to group by the custid (and any other columns you want to select without aggregrating) as well. Then order the results by order_count to ensure the 3 selected have the highest order count.

```
SELECT c.custid, c.name, c.order_count, SUM( o.total ) AS Totalspent 
FROM customer c 
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.custid = o.custid 
GROUP BY c.custid, c.name, c.order_count
ORDER BY c.order_count DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote. sorry about that.

Comment: Terrific! Happy I could help